# How to configure WebMatrix for custom file extensions to be interpreted as PHP file?

Tags: php, webmatrix

**Scenario:** I am using Microsoft's WebMatrix 3 as a IDE for editing PHP website. But on the  server we are configuring Nginx to to interpret all custom extension (say .stack) as PHP.

**Issue**: In WebMatrix I am unable to use any PHP specific IntelliSense (PHP specific syntax highlighting) while editing. When its .php extension by default WebMatrix works fine.

I tried to figure out how to add custom extension to make WebMatrix to interpret those file as php script, but no luck. So please if any one has a solution share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following working solution:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\config\filetypes.xml

Find *.php* in the above file.

You will find something like: `<FileType extension=".php;.phtml">`

Edit this line and add your custom file extension (say .stack). So that it should look like: `<FileType extension=".php;.phtml;.stack">`

Restart WebMatrix it will interpret all *.stack* file extensions as PHP files.

Happy Coding :)